# Maintain List ID when moving a list from one farm to another

Tags: list

Is there a way to move a list from one farm to another farm site collection with out having the LIST GUID change?

Currently I have tried to do this and was sucessful at moving the list and contents to the farm using a template export and import...however the GUID on the list changes and I was hoping to preserve that.

As I understand the list GUID is random upon creation and assume that because I'm importing the list as a new list off the template that it would create a new ID...but want to know if there is a way to adjust it after the fact or another method that would preserve the GUID.

I read through this post [Moving list from one environment to another while preserving the GUID](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/26247/moving-list-from-one-environment-to-another-while-preserving-the-guid) and was wondering if this is the only solution? Anyone had sucess with third party stuff?

Comment: Can you explain how your question is different than the one you linked to? This seems like a duplicate to me...

Comment: The author in mentioned link is spoke of using a .stp template file. My question is more of a general can it be done and if people do it how do they normally go about doing it? Are they leverging 3rd party? or is the only solution just as presented in the mentioned article of a database refresh?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so to answer my own question on this one, i was able to do this by first moving the lists i needed into a isolated site collection, then i was able to leverage sharepoint backup to capture that site collection and then restore it back down to my development environment. The GUID's never changes in that operation.

They did change when i moved them from the old location to the new site collection and i never found away around this...from what i read it is by design and you really can't manipulate it with out alot of work.